# Adding protocols to a class optionally

Tags: ios

I have a class which do not confirms to a particular protocol.

xyzClass:UIVIewController <>
 Now in one instance of that class i want that protocol to be used.

xyzClass:uiviewController

How can i add it on run time? or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the protocol method(s) optional

```
@protocol <...> NSObject
@required
 (required methods here)
@optional
 (optional methods here)
@end
```

Just be sure to test that selector responds:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDoSomething)])
{
  [delegate didDoSomething]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want use the protocol only in one instance, you can declare a delegate property and the protocol methods as optionals. In one instance, delegate property is nil, in the other one you will instantiate the property.

You have to declare the protocol methods as RegularExpression said

```
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSomething)])
{
    [self.delegate didSomething];
}
```

So, if the delegate is not instantiate (first case), the app will not crash.